# How to send Suricata log to Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, suricata, ids

After install and config Suricata 5.0.2 according to document https://suricata.readthedocs.io/.

I try to change some configuration in suricata.yaml by adding:

```
- alert-json-log:
      enabled: yes
      filetype: kafka
      kafka:
        brokers: > 
         xxx-kafka-online003:9092,
         xxx-kafka-online004:9092,
         xxx-kafka-online005:9092,
         xxx-kafka-online006:9092,
         xxx-kafka-online007:9092
        topic: nsm_event
        partitions: 5
      http: yes
```

Next I run Suricata, and receive the error 
Invalid entry for alert-json-log.filetype.  Expected "regular" (default), "unix_stream", "pcie" or "unix_dgram"

[image]

I don't know to configure on Suricata to enable sending log to Kafka topics.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see Kafka listed as an output type, therefore "no, there is not"

Refer docs: https://suricata.readthedocs.io/en/suricata-5.0.2/output/index.html

Plus, I'm not sure I understand what you expect `http: yes` to do since Kafka is not an HTTP service

---

What you **could** do is set `filetype: unix_stream`, then I assume that is Syslog, and you can add another service like Kafka Connect or Fluentd or Logstash to route that data to Kafka.

In other words, services don't need to integrate with Kafka. Plenty of alternatives exist to read files or `stdout`/`stderr`/`syslog` streams

Comment: This doesn't answer the question "How to send Suricata log to Kafka?" This is more like a comment.

Comment: @jallen0927 It is an answer. StackOverflow won't let me write "no, there isn't", though